# When is the group algebra $L^1(G)$ semisimple?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, banach-algebras

Let $G$ be locally compact group. Define group algebra as 
$$L^1(G)=\{f\colon G\to\Bbb{C}\mid\int\lvert f(x)\rvert\, dx<\infty\}$$
with convolution product. When is the group algebra $L^1(G)$ semisimple?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Always, according to Naĭmark, *Normed Algebras*, VII p. 380.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a simple proof?

Comment: Naĭmark's proof is pretty simple: if $f$ is in the reducing ideal of $L^1(G)$, i.e. $m(f^*\cdot f)=0$ for every positive linear functional $m$ on $L^1(G)$, then $\|f\cdot\varphi\|_2^2=(\varphi,f^*\cdot f\cdot\varphi)=0$ for all $\varphi\in L^2(G)$. So $\int f(g)\varphi(g^{-1}h)dg=0$ for all $\varphi\in L^2(G)$ and almost all $h\in G$. Taking for $\varphi$ the characteristic function of an arbitrary summable set, one concludes that $f(g)=0$ almost everywhere on $G$, qed.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer also in corollary 4.34 page 103 of a book which was named "**A course in abstract harmonic analysis**" By **Folland**. In there it was proven that for any locally compact commutative group $G$ the group algebra $L^1(G)$ and measure algebra $M(G)$ are semi-simple.

Comment: Your question did not assume G is commutative. The result you state here only applies to commutative groups

Comment: Unless you have misquoted Folland?

Comment: It is semisimple for every $G$

Comment: When is the group $C$-star of $G$ ,$C^*(G)$, semi-simple? Does it depend on  the group $G$?